# Changing role hierarchy with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a new role in discord.py.

But I want this role to be in the (let's say) 3rd spot of the roles.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use [`Role.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.edit), passing a `position` value, which must be lower than the position of your highest role.

```
@bot.command()
async def moverole(ctx, role: discord.Role, pos: int):
    try:
        await role.edit(position=pos)
        await ctx.send("Role moved.")
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send("You do not have permission to do that")
    except discord.HTTPException:
        await ctx.send("Failed to move role")
    except discord.InvalidArgument:
        await ctx.send("Invalid argument")
```

Answer (score 1):

[`discord.Client.move_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.12/api.html#discord.Client.move_role) seems to be what you're after