# Discord.py - Move Role higher

Tags: python, discord.py

So i want that the Bot to move a Role higher.
If you dont understand what i mean, [look at this Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb3tr.png)

Now i want the Bot to move Test Role 2 above Test Role. It shouldnt move a Role above a certain Role, just as high as the bot can get, sometimes there is a Lock on the Role, then it should put Test Role 2 directly under the Role with the Lock, that would the highest that it could get.
(I hope you understand what i mean)
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing role hierarchy with discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975932/changing-role-hierarchy-with-discord-py)

Comment: @BenSoyka Kind of, the Problem is, i want it to put it as high as it can, not on a certain place

Comment: @BenSoyka Nevermind, solved it with a While Loop and a try, thanks!