# How can i create roles and put them on top?discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

my bot has a command called mute and basically, it creates a role and gives it to the person but the problem is when it does that ppl with higher roles still are able to talk. how can I put the mute role on top of every role in the server? and I mean in every server, not just one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing role hierarchy with discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975932/changing-role-hierarchy-with-discord-py)

Answer (score 1):

So you can't put the `mute` role above the bot role, but the following should help:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
        guild = ctx.guild
        role = await guild.create_role(name='muted', hoist=True)
        all_roles = await guild.fetch_roles()
        num_roles = len(all_roles)
        print(f'The server has {num_roles} roles.')
        await role.edit(reason=None, position=num_roles - 2)
        print('Created new role!')
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f'{member} has been muted.)
```

So what we did is check how many roles the server has, create a new role and put it to the top/under the bot role.

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing a role to a position lower than the top, I would suggest using the role.edit method, passing a position value.

However, as for your question, which is putting a role at the top after creating this, you should use the [discord.Client.move_role()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.12/api.html#discord.Client.move_role)

As for actually creating the role:

If you're on the rewrite, use this

```
guild = ctx.guild
await guild.create_role(name="role name")
```

and change "role name" with the name of the role you want to create. If you want to make the role depending on what the user says you can do something likes this:

```
@client.command()
async def rolecreate(ctx, arg):
   guild = ctx.guild
   await guild.create_role(name=arg)
```

---

### Here, you'd have to do (lets say your prefix is !): "!rolecreate Moderator" and it would only create a role.

For the async branch:

```
author = ctx.message.author
await client.create_role(author.server, name="role name")
```

---

Just in case you want the bot to have a command that adds the role here you go:
For the rewrite branch

```
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="role to add name")
user = ctx.message.author
await user.add_roles(role)
```

If you want to add a role mentioned in the command, you do for example:

```
@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx, arg):
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=arg)
  user = ctx.message.author
  await user.add_roles(role)
```

---

For the async branch:

```
user = ctx.message.author
role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="role to add name")
await client.add_roles(user, role)
```

---

Hope this helped!

Comment: The async branch is not supported anymore, it doesn't even work, there's no need to put examples for it

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński oop- sorry I didn't know since I mostly use the rewrite