What is the argument for the position of a role in the create_role(...) module for discord.py? A
I'm trying to create a bot that uses a user input (hex code) to create a role with a custom color as an alternative to reaction roles. However, the position of the role is set to default (1) so the color won't show up if the user has a higher role.
Code:
async def supercolor(ctx, hexcode):
  await ctx.send(hexcode)
  guild = ctx.guild
  newhex = "0x".join(hexcode)
  await guild.create_role(name=hexcode, color=discord.Color(newhex))
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=hexcode)
  user = ctx.message.author
  await user.add_roles(role)

What is the argument to put in create_role(name=hex code, color=discord.Color(newhex)) to make it have a higher positon? I've tried position and pos

take a look at this, maybe this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975932/changing-role-hierarchy-with-discord-py

Form official documentation: create and edit role
